# Embedded pages using doFilter in xhtml not working

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have a applied a Filter in my project as follows :

```
public class Filter implements javax.servlet.Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("admin") == null) {
                // Not logged in, so redirect request to login page.
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("../index.xhtml");
            }
        }


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

and its entry inside web.xml is as follows

```
<filter>  
        <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>com.kc.aop.bean.Filter</filter-class>  
  </filter> 
  <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>  
   </filter-mapping>
```

I have the following files inside my admin folder :

```
dashboard.xhtml
introduction.xhtml
news.xhtml
```

introduction.xhtml and news.xhtml are embbeded inside dashboard.xhtml using

```
<iframe id= "iframe" width="1000px" height="300px" src="introduction.xhtml"></iframe>
```

I have a login in my index.xhtml, but when i try to login, i can see my dashboard.xhtml, but the iframe which uses introduction.xhtml shows the following error.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:8080/AOP/admin/introduction.xhtml
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Any idea, why such a behaviur. Is their something wrong with my doFilter implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` in your `doFilter` method implementation. Otherwise the rest of your filters won't get invoked.